# Ubuntu not compatible with my custom built desktop

Tags: server, graphics, gpu, compatibility, mint

I custom built a desktop PC today, and I'd like to run ubuntu 15.10 on it. It boots up, then right when I start to see unity desktop, I get a white, unresponsive screen (no mouse showing or anything). Upon further inspection, I realized that I get basically the same problem when running Linux Mint. I also realized that ubuntu server can get up and running just fine. I created a windows installation disk, and ran that as well. I found that I can run that just fine. So it must be a linux thing.

The components that could be the source of the problem are used in my PC are:
Intel Core i5-6600 (Processor)
Asrock B150 Gaming K4 ATX LGA1151 (Motherboard)
MSI Radeon R7 370 2GB (Video Card)

For a full part list click:
http://pcpartpicker.com/parts/partlist/

So I'm basically thinking that there is an incompatibility between my GPU (graphics card) and Linux.

Any info is much appreciated, THANKS UBUNTU!

Comment: Did you try to run/boot any other OS on it? Does the installation itself work, does the ubuntu life CD or live thumb drive boot? I recommend to accept to install updates while installation if possible. If I remember correctly your GPU is pretty new and needs the new amd drivers, which should be included in Ubuntu 15.10 (uses Kernel 4.20 or so). Still, the new drivers may not be as stable yet as we would like to. If you use CTRL+ALT+F1, can you access (see) the terminal or is everything still white?

Comment: @verpfeilt I ran a windows 10 installation disk, but did not actually install it. I was able to get the whole GUI though. Also, there is no time when the machine will accept any user input, it just boots, loads for a while, and fails. I cannot access the terminal.

Comment: @Mezex – did you end up solving this issue?